# Delete rows after creating strings containing specific values in a sub-routine in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to call sub-routine to remove rows that contain a certain value in a cell from my column colCell. So we are creating a string that contains '' if it cannot identify any values on another sheet to create the string from.

```
aCell.Value = Replace(aCell.Value, Split(aCell.Value, ",")(1), "'" & Sheet5.Cells(colCell.Row, 2) & "'")
DeleteRows (colCell)
```

I thought I could call the sub-routine above and pass in the column variable?

Main sub-routine:

Sub Main()

```
Set wDFS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set colCell = wDFS.Rows("1:1").Find(what:="New query", after:=wDFS.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not colCell Is Nothing Then
Set rng = wDFS.Range(wDFS.Cells(2, colCell.Column), wDFS.Cells(wDFS.UsedRange.Rows.Count, colCell.Column))
For Each aCell In rng
    Set colCell = Sheet5.Range("A1:A" & Sheet5.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Find(what:=Replace(Split(aCell.Value, ",")(1), "'", ""), after:=wDFS.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not colCell Is Nothing Then
        aCell.Value = Replace(aCell.Value, Split(aCell.Value, ",")(1), "'" & Sheet5.Cells(colCell.Row, 2) & "'")
        DeleteRows (colCell)
    Else
        With Sheet5.Range("A" & Sheet5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            .Value = Replace(Split(aCell.Value, ",")(1), "'", "")
            .Interior.Color = 255
        End With
    End If
Next aCell
Else
MsgBox "No new query column found in " & wDFS.Name & " sheet"
End If

End Sub
```

Sub-routine for deleting rows:

```
Sub DeleteRows(colCell)
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("Data", ActiveSheet.Range(colCell).End(xlUp))
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("''", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

In th debug, it says there is an issue with the following line:

```
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("DataFeedSheet", ActiveSheet.Range(colCell).End(xlUp))
```

I assume it is something related to the range I have specified.

How do you do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `DeleteRows()` subroutine you've supplied does not accept a parameter.  And you're missing a `Sub main()` line (or whatever you want to call it) at the start of your main code chunk

Comment: I left it out, but have now included it.

Comment: Added further information about the line highlighted from the debug

Comment: It's still hard to answer the question without knowing what the macro is trying to do.  Maybe add a screenshot of your worksheet?  I'm trying to run sample code and it trips before if even reaches your `DeleteRows` function

Comment: The macro looks at two columns on a separate sheet, if both columns contain a value for the row then it will add a particular value to a string on the "Data" sheet. If one of the columns does not contain a value then it will add a value of "''" to the string on the "Data" sheet. I would like to delete rows on the "Data" sheet where colCell contains the value "''" in any of its cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteRow4()

Dim rng As Range, cell_search As Range, del As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Range("Data"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
For Each cell_search In rng
    If (cell_search.Value) = "9999" Then
```

'Your specific cell value goes here

```
        If del Is Nothing Then
            Set del = cell_search
            Else: Set del = Union(del, cell_search)
        End If
    End If
    Next cell_search
    On Error Resume Next
    del.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a <Method 'Range' of object ' _Global' failed> message

Comment: Try to specify the sheet the range "Data" is on like Sheets(1).Range("Data"). That might prove to be the issue.